# How do I create checkerboard with set heigt

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I have created a checker board that's 4x4 in JS, but I want to make it 4x5(5 being the width) using Java. but whenever I add squares they go the bottom when I want them to go to the side, and I think the css is the issue here, so if  you could tell me what css I should use for this that would be great.

This is my css:

```
.board {
  display: grid;
  width: 850px;
  height: 850px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
}
.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 150px;
}
```

and I know having set width and heights is not good for what I am attempting but removing them just throws all my squares in disarray. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);` -- using `repeat` lets you be more flexible with future changes like this.

Comment: It does not seem to help it. This is how my board looks right now: https://gyazo.com/7ac95a9f00a547c92005319445e7918b And this is how my board looks with this option: https://gyazo.com/a5378ca87ecc83478ed9a7873678e204.  UPDATE: using repeat(4,1fr) does seem to maintain the board, but the following squares still go to the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set it to be 4 columns. Change the grid template from columns to rows

```
.board {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 200px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 200px);
}
.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 150px;
}
```

Comment: sorry, you must add: grid-auto-flow: column;

Comment: yes that is it! And do you think I can remove the height and width? Because they try to fit the 850x850 limit I put so they stick together

Comment: sure, you could remove the height at least

Comment: but they immediately start sticking together. That would be a second issue if you are willing to help me with that. Now when I add the extra squares to my current board I get 8 more, so my total 24 are trying to fit the height and witdh so they have no space in between them. But when I remove either the height or width they stick together from the get go, without my adding any squares.

Comment: I edited the response. Added grid-gap: 10px

Comment: Yes! I appreciate it a lot!